# Formik onChange executing but not changing Field Value?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

Hey folks I have a weird issue, I think. I have a Formik form i'm using that utilizes Select fields. I'd like it operate in the following:

Select A allows you to select a County
Select C allows you to select a City.

When a user selects a different option for Select A, the app should reset the value of Select C to "all" or to refetch the new Citys for Select A. If Select A == "all" then don't show Select C.

I have attempted to do this utilizing a onChange prop, which the logic in it works....but the actual field that the onChange is assigned to won't change the actual value, instead it'll stay on the prior value.

Here is the troublesome code:

SELECT A:

```
<div className="field">
            <label id="search-region" className="label" htmlFor="region">
              Region
            </label>
            <Field
              name="region"
              as="select"
              labelid="search-region"
              label="Region"
              className="input"
              onChange={(e) => (values.city = "all")}
            >
              <option value="all">All</option>
              {regions.nodes.map((region) => {
                return (
                  <option key={region.id} value={region.name}>
                    {region.name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </Field>
          </div>
```

SELECT C:

```
{query.region != "all" ? (
            <div className="field">
              <label id="search-cities" className="label" htmlFor="city">
                City in Region
              </label>
              <Field
                name="city"
                as="select"
                labelid="search-cities"
                label="Cities"
                className="input"
              >
                <option value="all">All</option>
                {uniqueData.sort()}
                {uniqueData.map((town) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={town} value={town}>
                      {town}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </Field>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
```

I appreciate any help. The full code is below:

```
const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log("values: ", values);
    const campfeatures = Array.isArray(values.campfeatures)
      ? values.campfeatures.map(({ value }) => value).join(",")
      : (values.campfeatures = "all");

    Router.push(
      {
        pathname: "/camps",
        query: { ...values, campfeatures },
      },
      undefined,
      { shallow: true }
    ).then(async () => {
      refetch();
    });
  };

  const initialValues = {
    region: query.region || "all",
    camptype: query.camptype || "all",
    city: query.city || "all",
    // campfeatures: query.features || "all",
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      enableReinitialize={true}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {({ values, submitForm }) => (
        <Form>
          <div className="field">
            <label id="search-region" className="label" htmlFor="region">
              Region
            </label>
            <Field
              name="region"
              as="select"
              labelid="search-region"
              label="Region"
              className="input"
              // onChange={(e) => (values.city = "all")}
            >
              <option value="all">All</option>
              {regions.nodes.map((region) => {
                return (
                  <option key={region.id} value={region.name}>
                    {region.name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </Field>
          </div>

          <div className="field">
            <label id="search-type" className="label" htmlFor="camptype">
              Type
            </label>
            <Field
              name="camptype"
              as="select"
              labelid="search-type"
              label="Type"
              className="input"
            >
              <option value="all">All</option>
              {camptypes.nodes.map((camp) => {
                return (
                  <option key={camp.id} value={camp.name}>
                    {camp.name}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </Field>
          </div>

          <div className="field">
            <label id="search-feat" className="label" htmlFor="search-feat">
              Features:
            </label>
            <Field
              component={SelectField}
              name="campfeatures"
              labelid="search-feat"
              label="Features"
              options={selectObjects}
            />
          </div>

          {query.region != "all" ? (
            <div className="field">
              <label id="search-cities" className="label" htmlFor="city">
                City in Region
              </label>
              <Field
                name="city"
                as="select"
                labelid="search-cities"
                label="Cities"
                className="input"
              >
                <option value="all">All</option>
                {uniqueData.sort()}
                {uniqueData.map((town) => {
                  return (
                    <option key={town} value={town}>
                      {town}
                    </option>
                  );
                })}
              </Field>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <div className="field">
            <button type="button" className="button" onClick={submitForm}>
              Search Campgrounds
            </button>
          </div>

          <div className="column mt-5 is-full campgroundResults">
            {campResults[0] != "No Campgrounds Found" ? (
              <div className="campgroundresultsHeader">
                <p>Results:</p>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="campgroundresultsHeader">
                <p>No Campground's Found, Please Search Again.</p>
              </div>
            )}
            <CampgroundResults
              campResults={campResults}
              setViewport={setViewport}
              paginationInfo={paginationInfo}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="pageButtons">
            {paginationInfo[0].hasPreviousPage ? (
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  fetchMore({
                    variables: {
                      first: null,
                      after: null,
                      last: 10,
                      before: paginationInfo[0].startCursor || null,
                    },
                    updateQuery,
                  });
                }}
              >
                Previous Listings
              </button>
            ) : null}

            {paginationInfo[0].hasNextPage ? (
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  fetchMore({
                    variables: {
                      first: 10,
                      after: paginationInfo[0].endCursor || null,
                      last: null,
                      before: null,
                    },
                    updateQuery,
                  });
                }}
              >
                Next Listings
              </button>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you have to set the field value for that field also.

```
 onChange={(e) => {
                setFieldValue("city", "all"),
                  setFieldValue("region", e.target.value);
              }}
```